# Trying to call from a .txt file and trying to use int.Parse but not working

Tags: c#, parsing, int

[Trying to call from a .txt file and trying to use int.Parse but not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHCef.png)

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Put you code in not an image of it. Also that's a compile time error. Help us to help you...

Answer (score 0):

A proper way of creating a DateTime object using int.Parse:

```
string year = "1994";
string month = "1";
string day = "14";
DateTime start = new DateTime(int.Parse(year), int.Parse(month), int.Parse(day));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine the offending line(s):

```
DateTime Start = int.Parse(readValues[3],
                            readValues[4],
                            readValues[5],
                            readValues[6],
                            readValues[7]);
```

You're declaring the variable Start as `DateTime` and yet parsing it as an `int`. My question would be: what kind of value are you reading, a Date, or an Integer?

That aside, you are passing several arguments to `int.Parse` and one can't tell what your intention is.

I'm going out on a limb here but I believe that line should either read:

`DateTime Start = DateTime.Parse(readValues[3]);`

or

`int Start = int.Parse(readValues[3]);`